# How can SQL throw Column invalid because not in aggregate and not in GROUP BY when GROUP BY is not used anywhere

Tags: sql-server, group-by

When trying to use a reporting system of a GpsGate server I tried it to get me only the first and the last trip of a day per user.

The system is too obscure really to get any help for that but I stumbled upon an SQL Error which I thought impossible and maybe if I understand the reason I can fix the SQL so the report?!

The thing is I get the following error:

> Column 'DistanceDetailed.UserID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The thing is: There is no `GROUP BY` anywhere.

How can this error occur? Are there other things that can constitute grouping without using `GROUP BY` clause?

The whole SQL is very unreadable as the reporting system uses many sub-queries.

Please do not really try to understand what the whole thing does as it is just horrible to read. I just need a tip where any grouping will occur here:

```
SELECT
PeriodStart,
PeriodEnd,
ApplicationID,
SamplingStart AS StartTime,
SamplingEnd AS StopTime,
DistanceDetailed.Name
FROM
(
 SELECT
  CAST('2022-06-23T22:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS PeriodStart,
  CAST('2022-06-24T22:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS PeriodEnd,
  32 AS ApplicationID,
  Users.Username,
  Users.Name,
  DATEDIFF(
    SECOND,
    Distance01.SamplingStart,
    Distance01.SamplingEnd
  ) AS Duration,
      Distance01.SamplingStart,
      Distance01.SamplingEnd,
      Distance01.UserID,
      Distance01.StartAddress,
      Distance01.StopAddress,
      Distance01.DistanceGps,
      Distance01.DistanceOdo,
      Distance01.MaxSpeed,
      Distance01.AvgSpeed,
      Distance01.FatPointState,
      Distance01.Fuel
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
       data_time_stamp_start AS 'SamplingStart',
       data_time_stamp_end AS 'SamplingEnd',
       int_01 AS 'UserID',
       txt_01 AS 'StartAddress',
       txt_02 AS 'StopAddress',
       dbl_01 AS 'DistanceGps',
       dbl_02 AS 'DistanceOdo',
       dbl_03 AS 'MaxSpeed',
       dbl_04 AS 'AvgSpeed',
       dbl_05 AS 'Fuel',
       txt_03 AS 'FatPointState'
      FROM
      reportv3_data_store
      LEFT JOIN reportv3_data_store_ext01 ON reportv3_data_store.report_data_store_id = reportv3_data_store_ext01.report_data_store_id
     WHERE
      report_data_provider_id = 1
      AND int_01 IN (258, 259)
      AND application_id = 32
      AND data_time_stamp_start BETWEEN '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
      AND '2022-06-24T22:00:00'
      AND data_time_stamp_end BETWEEN '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
      AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2022-06-24T22:00:00')
      AND (
        true_break = 1
        OR (
          true_break = 0
          AND data_time_stamp_start != data_time_stamp_end
        )
      )
  ) AS Distance01
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT u.user_id AS UserID,
      u.username as Username,
      u.name as Name,
      u.description as Description,
      u.Surname as Surname,
      email as Email,
      driver_id as IButton
    FROM
      users u
      JOIN user_groups ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
      JOIN groups g ON g.group_id = ug.group_id
      AND g.application_id = 32
  ) AS Users ON Users.UserID = Distance01.UserID
WHERE
  Distance01.UserID IN (
    SELECT
      UserID
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          tu.user_id AS UserID,
          t.tag_id AS TagID,
          t.tag_name AS Name,
          t.tag_description AS Description
        FROM
          tag t
          JOIN tag_users tu ON tu.tag_id = t.tag_id
        WHERE
          bo_type = 'Franson.Directory.UserTagWriter'
          AND t.application_id = 32
      ) AS TagUsers
    WHERE
      TagUsers.TagID IN (297)
  )
  AND Distance01.SamplingStart >= '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
  AND Distance01.SamplingEnd <= '2022-06-24T22:00:00'
  AND Distance01.FatPointState != 'sleep'
) AS DistanceDetailed
 JOIN (
  SELECT
    MIN(SamplingStart) AS StartOfDay,
    DistanceDetailed.UserID,
    DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, SamplingStart)) AS DayOfMonth
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CAST('2022-06-23T22:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS PeriodStart,
      CAST('2022-06-24T22:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS PeriodEnd,
      32 AS ApplicationID,
      Users.Username,
      Users.Name,
      DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,
        Distance01.SamplingStart,
        Distance01.SamplingEnd
      ) AS Duration,
      Distance01.SamplingStart,
      Distance01.SamplingEnd,
      Distance01.UserID,
      Distance01.StartAddress,
      Distance01.StopAddress,
      Distance01.DistanceGps,
      Distance01.DistanceOdo,
      Distance01.MaxSpeed,
      Distance01.AvgSpeed,
      Distance01.FatPointState,
      Distance01.Fuel
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          data_time_stamp_start AS 'SamplingStart',
          data_time_stamp_end AS 'SamplingEnd',
          int_01 AS 'UserID',
          txt_01 AS 'StartAddress',
          txt_02 AS 'StopAddress',
          dbl_01 AS 'DistanceGps',
          dbl_02 AS 'DistanceOdo',
          dbl_03 AS 'MaxSpeed',
          dbl_04 AS 'AvgSpeed',
          dbl_05 AS 'Fuel',
          txt_03 AS 'FatPointState'
        FROM
          reportv3_data_store
          LEFT JOIN reportv3_data_store_ext01 ON reportv3_data_store.report_data_store_id = reportv3_data_store_ext01.report_data_store_id
        WHERE
          report_data_provider_id = 1
          AND int_01 IN (
            258,
            259
          )
          AND application_id = 32
          AND data_time_stamp_start BETWEEN '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
          AND '2022-06-24T22:00:00'
          AND data_time_stamp_end BETWEEN '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
          AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2022-06-24T22:00:00')
          AND (
            true_break = 1
            OR (
              true_break = 0
              AND data_time_stamp_start != data_time_stamp_end
            )
          )
      ) AS Distance01
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          DISTINCT u.user_id AS UserID,
          u.username as Username,
          u.name as Name,
          u.description as Description,
          u.Surname as Surname,
          email as Email,
          driver_id as IButton
        FROM
          users u
          JOIN user_groups ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
          JOIN groups g ON g.group_id = ug.group_id
          AND g.application_id = 32
      ) AS Users ON Users.UserID = Distance01.UserID
    WHERE
      Distance01.UserID IN (
        SELECT
          UserID
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              tu.user_id AS UserID,
              t.tag_id AS TagID,
              t.tag_name AS Name,
              t.tag_description AS Description
            FROM
              tag t
              JOIN tag_users tu ON tu.tag_id = t.tag_id
            WHERE
              bo_type = 'Franson.Directory.UserTagWriter'
              AND t.application_id = 32
          ) AS TagUsers
        WHERE
          TagUsers.TagID IN (297)
      )
      AND Distance01.SamplingStart >= '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
      AND Distance01.SamplingEnd <= '2022-06-24T22:00:00'
      AND Distance01.FatPointState != 'sleep'
  ) AS DistanceDetailed
) AS StartTag ON StartTag.UserID = DistanceDetailed.UserID
 AND DistanceDetailed.FatPointState = 'run'
 AND DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, SamplingStart)) = DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, StartTag.StartOfDay))
JOIN (
 SELECT
  MAX(SamplingStart) AS EndOfDay,
  DistanceDetailed.UserID,
  DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, SamplingStart)) AS DayOfMonth
 FROM
  (
    SELECT
      CAST('2022-06-23T22:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS PeriodStart,
      CAST('2022-06-24T22:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS PeriodEnd,
      32 AS ApplicationID,
      Users.Username,
      Users.Name,
      DATEDIFF(
        SECOND,
        Distance01.SamplingStart,
        Distance01.SamplingEnd
      ) AS Duration,         
      Distance01.SamplingStart,
      Distance01.SamplingEnd,
      Distance01.UserID,
      Distance01.StartAddress,
      Distance01.StopAddress,
      Distance01.DistanceGps,
      Distance01.DistanceOdo,
      Distance01.MaxSpeed,
      Distance01.AvgSpeed,
      Distance01.FatPointState,
      Distance01.Fuel
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          data_time_stamp_start AS 'SamplingStart',
          data_time_stamp_end AS 'SamplingEnd',
          int_01 AS 'UserID',
          txt_01 AS 'StartAddress',
          txt_02 AS 'StopAddress',
          dbl_01 AS 'DistanceGps',
          dbl_02 AS 'DistanceOdo',
          dbl_03 AS 'MaxSpeed',
          dbl_04 AS 'AvgSpeed',
          dbl_05 AS 'Fuel',
          txt_03 AS 'FatPointState'
        FROM
          reportv3_data_store
          LEFT JOIN reportv3_data_store_ext01 ON reportv3_data_store.report_data_store_id = reportv3_data_store_ext01.report_data_store_id
        WHERE
          report_data_provider_id = 1
          AND int_01 IN (
            258,
            259
          )
          AND application_id = 32
          AND data_time_stamp_start BETWEEN '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
          AND '2022-06-24T22:00:00'
          AND data_time_stamp_end BETWEEN '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
          AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2022-06-24T22:00:00')
          AND (
            true_break = 1
            OR (
              true_break = 0
              AND data_time_stamp_start != data_time_stamp_end
            )
          )
      ) AS Distance01
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          DISTINCT u.user_id AS UserID,
          u.username as Username,
          u.name as Name,
          u.description as Description,
          u.Surname as Surname,
          email as Email,
          driver_id as IButton
        FROM
          users u
          JOIN user_groups ug ON u.user_id = ug.user_id
          JOIN groups g ON g.group_id = ug.group_id
          AND g.application_id = 32
      ) AS Users ON Users.UserID = Distance01.UserID
    WHERE
      Distance01.UserID IN (
        SELECT
          UserID
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              tu.user_id AS UserID,
              t.tag_id AS TagID,
              t.tag_name AS Name,
              t.tag_description AS Description
            FROM
              tag t
              JOIN tag_users tu ON tu.tag_id = t.tag_id
            WHERE
              bo_type = 'Franson.Directory.UserTagWriter'
              AND t.application_id = 32
          ) AS TagUsers
        WHERE
          TagUsers.TagID IN (297)
      )
      AND Distance01.SamplingStart >= '2022-06-23T22:00:00'
      AND Distance01.SamplingEnd <= '2022-06-24T22:00:00'
      AND Distance01.FatPointState != 'sleep'
  ) AS DistanceDetailed
) AS EndeTag ON EndeTag.UserID = DistanceDetailed.UserID
AND DistanceDetailed.FatPointState = 'run'
AND DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, SamplingStart)) = DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, EndeTag.EndOfDay))
ORDER BY
  DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(SECOND, 7200, SamplingStart)),
  DistanceDetailed.UserID
```

Comment: Because you have non-windowed aggregate functions, and in the same scope have non-aggregated columns you *must* have a `GROUP BY` clause. Your omission of the `GROUP BY` is therefore the flaw, or your other columns should be being aggregated, so that you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause..

Comment: You have MIN(SamplingStart) with no group by.

Comment: `MAX(SamplingStart) OVER (PARTITION BY DistanceDetails.UserID) AS EndOfDay`??

Comment: Notice that the error messages says "either...or" rather than "and" as you've put in the title. Using an aggregate function without `group by` *implies* a kind of logical grouping along the lines of `group by 'All' -- *invalid sql`. That is it collapses all rows to a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have non-windowed aggregate functions, and in the same scope have non-aggregated columns you must have a GROUP BY clause. Your omission of the GROUP BY is therefore the flaw, or your other columns should be being aggregated, so that you don't need a GROUP BY clause.

For instance this query

```
select max(OrderDate) OrderDate, SalesOrderID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

fails with the same error.  Aparently some engines allow this, and treat it as a global aggregate, which SQL Server requires you to use windowing aggregate for:

```
select max(OrderDate) over () OrderDate, SalesOrderID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

> When trying to use a reporting system

So this appears to be a bug in the reporting system.